# Meteor.js - how do I include a debugOnly package when I deploy to production?

Tags: meteor

I would like to deploy a meteor app and I would like all packages bundled and deployed, including those marked as `debugOnly` -- how can I accomplish this? I am using Arunoda's `mup` and `mupx` tools for some deploys and pushing to Heroku for others.

Thanks.

Comment: Aren't some of these packages voluntarily debug-only because they include blatant security issues, such as all-powerful methods and/or publications (like `msavin:mongol`I suppose)?

Comment: yes, I would like `msavin:mongol` and also Velocity running in my production environment.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "voluntarily" debug-only.  They are apparently marked that way when I add the packages, so for me it is effectively involuntary.  I would like to know how to set `debugOnly=false` after I've added the package.

Comment: "Voluntarily" as in "this package has the potential of letting any user observe/manipulate/delete/add/corrupt any kind of data so I probably don't want this code running anywhere near a production server any time in the future"?

Comment: I guess I have to just clone the package and turn the flag off myself...

Comment: Before you do that, make sure that the package does not include authoritative subscriptions and/or methods. Your mention of "production environment" means that you absolutely don't want any kind of sneaky authority on your data.

Comment: Thanks, I've taken care of all concerns along those lines.  Now I just need to know how to turn the debugOnly flag off.

Comment: Download this package(from github), put in in /packages directory in your meteor project, change package.js and that's it, when you run this it will load data from local package, not atmosphere

Comment: I created a `packages/` directory, I entered this directory and cloned both msavin Mongol and msavin JetSetter, I changed debugOnly in each of their `package.js` files and I then deployed the app to production -- but it didn't work...

Comment: Maybe try removing them inconsole, and then add them again, I don't exactly remember if packages directory is checked every run

Comment: @JonCrowell I tried the same (adding the packages locally and changing the debugOnly flag). I didn't work here either. I am deploying with mupx. Have you had any luck getting the msavin:mongol package working after deploy?

Answer (score 3):

When you run `meteor deploy --debug`, it will deploy your application the same way as it is in development mode. I'd bet running `meteor build --debug` would yield the same results.

Of course, this may not be a good idea with with debugOnly packages :)